# Automatic aging-out (deletion) of old records in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, delete, queue

Does Postgres have any features to support aging-out old records?

I want to use Postgres for logging, as a sort of queue, where records (log events) older than two weeks are automatically deleted.

Comment: Use partitioning. Just deleting records will not reduce the table size on disk.

Comment: @sivann Doesn't your recommendation assume his issue is disk size? If his problem is query execution time it seems like deletion might be a possibly simpler answer than partitioning, no? (still trying to understand this myself)

Comment: The problem is simply that log records are no longer interesting after a certain amount of time. Deleting old rows should make room for new fresh rows.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no feature built in to delete rows automatically on a time-based regime (that I would know of).

You could run a daily (you decide) **cron-job** to schedule simple `DELETE` commands or use [**pgAgent**](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/pgagent.html) for the purpose.

Or you could use [**partitioning**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html) with weekly partitions. That makes deleting *very cheap*: just keep the latest two weeks and drop older partitions.

Before Postgres 10, partitioning was always [based on inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-IMPLEMENTATION-INHERITANCE). The new [declarative partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) has a lot of advantages and is improved further with every release. Inheritance still provides one key advantage, though. The manual:

> Some operations require a stronger lock when using declarative
> partitioning than when using table inheritance. For example, adding or
> removing a partition to or from a partitioned table requires taking an
> `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the parent table, whereas a `SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE` lock is enough in the case of regular inheritance.

Meaning, adding or removing a partition does not interfere with readers and writers of other partitions with inheritance, while everything is blocked with declarative partitioning (when going through the parent table). It's a *very fast* operation, though.

With *inheritance*, create partitions that [inherit from a "master" table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21145111/939860), lets call it `log`. Create a `RULE` or a `TRIGGER` on the master table that redirects INSERTs to the partition of the current week based on system time.

Either way, you can always log to the master table `log`. Create partitions ahead of time. Make that several weeks ahead to be sure and run a weekly cron job that adds future child tables ...

There are code examples in the manual for [inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-INHERITANCE-EXAMPLE) and [declarative partitioning.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE-EXAMPLE).

Related answer with a plpgsql function creating tables for inheritance automatically:

- [Drop certain tables in a function managing partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21541053/939860)

The related solution recreates a `RULE` to redirect INSERTs. A trigger function could write to the current partition dynamically ...

Comment: **Update:** Postgres 10 and later makes such partitioning easier. The [declarative partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) feature lets us specify the date range when defining the partition. So we no longer need create the `RULE` or `TRIGGER` as discussed in the middle of this Answer. To be clear, the cron jobs to create and delete the partitions as discussed in this Answer are still necessary.

Comment: This is interesting.  It seems to me though the drawbacks to using partitions on smaller tables (e.g. tables that aren't otherwise large enough to warrant partitioning) potentially outweigh deletions being "cheap".

Comment: @BasilBourque: Thank you for the update. I integrated declarative partitioning in the answer now.

Comment: @Madbreaks: Yes, the turning point depends on the sum total of typical operations. Very small tables are unlikely candidates. Keeping only one or two partitions at all times might tip the scales towards partitioning, as that negates most of the performance drawbacks. Also, declarative partitioning has become better with every release. It starts to shine with Postgres 12 (better yet, 13).

Comment: @Madbreaks Partitioning has numerous restrictions and trade-offs, and should be used only as a last resort. While it certainly can solve serious problems, use it judiciously. Be sure to do some deep study so you know the pros and cons. And keep up-to-date as this is an area of rapid development amongst the Postgres team.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter If I want to have a common mechanism for both Windows and Linux, which would be the best option to create one. I am shipping postgres for my application as both exe and rpm.

Comment: @abyin007: Not sure. [pgagent](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/pgagent.html) is available for Windows and Linux ...

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you use Postgres as time-series database. In that case, you might want to consider [TimescaleDB](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb), which is a time-series DB based on Postgres and is thus fully compatible with Postgres.

In Timescale, you first need to define a [hypertable](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hypertable/) (the primary Timescale data structure), then you can configure a retention policy using [`add_retention_policy`](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/data-retention/add_retention_policy/).